# Angular navigation issue (router.navigate)

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a problem at the navigation with angluar navigation.

I have a route like the following

```
     {
            path: 'truckdetails/:lieferNr',
            component: TruckDetailComponent,
            data: { state: 'truckdetail' },
            canActivate: [AuthguardService]
        },
```

If I using the routing like this

```
this.router.navigate(['truckdetails', delivery.LIEFER_NR]);
```

if I am using the following term

```
this.router.navigate(['truckdetails', response.data]);
```

I get the error that he can't find the route. I think it worked before I update anglular to the new version. But know I get error

```
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'truckdetails;lieferNr=00179324'
```

The Response also containing the lieferNr

```
{timestamp: 1530014875302, status: 200, message: "QRCode Scanned", data: {…}}
data :{lieferNr: "00179324"}
message : "QRCode Scanned"
status : 200
timestamp : 1530014875302
```

Comment: Could you please specify all of your app routes in your app-routing.module.ts file? I am asking because you might have another route that might be blocking the defined route.

Comment: Is `response.data` an object `{lieferNr: 00179324}`? That won't resolve to the route `truckdetails/00179324`; as you're seeing, it resolves to the route `truckdetails`, which isn't specified, with optional parameters `;lieferNr=00179324`. You need `response.data.lieferNr`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, yes it is an objetct out of an http request.

Comment: I'd suggest reading https://angular.io/guide/router, it talks about the various ways you can pass parameters to routes and the different outcomes.

Comment: you forgot the slash sign truckdetails/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`response.data` contains `{lieferNr: "00179324"}` which once serialized gives `lieferNr=00179324` when you want only `00179324`. Then use:

```
this.router.navigate(['truckdetails', response.data.lieferNr]);
```